# How can I use %autoreload on ipython parallel engines?

Tags: python, ipython, ipython-parallel

Is it possible to get the magic command %autoreload to work on remote ipengines?

The following works:

```
dv.execute('a=blah.test()')
dv.get('a')
5
```

I then change blah to return 8:

```
dv.execute('reload(blah)')
dv.execute('a=blah.test()')
dv.get('a')
8
```

But what I'd like to be able to do is:

```
dv.execute('%load_ext autoreload')
dv.execute('%autoreload 2')
```

And skip the reload step. However, when I try this the change does not take effect and blah.test() still uses the old version of the code. To be sure I'm not doing something wrong with the execute command, I also tried using the magic function:

```
%px %load_ext autoreload
%px %autoreload 2
```

Which still doesn't give me autoreloading functionality.

Thanks.